# byte-recompile-directory takes extremely long time to run

Tags: emacs, gnu

I want a emacs installation free from system-wide plugins installed. Gentoo installs them directly inside the *lisp* directory. So I created in my home separate *emacs/lisp* directory that contains only files from the emacs itself. Every time I run they are compiled. So I want to reduce run time and precompile this files.

I use `C-u 0 M-x byte-recompile-directory` to produce byte-compiled files. I have GNU Emacs 24.4.1

Firstly I've tried to byte-recompile a subdirectory 'lisp/calc' that have 44 files with total size of 2 Mb. Emacs take about 15 minutes of continuous working with 100% cpu load to byte-recompile the directory. I was thought that emacs has stuck somewhere, but it successfully completed task when I waited longer.

Now I'm trying to byte-recompile entire 'lisp' directory. The process is still loading my i5 processor for 100% in single thread. The top utility shows that it have already consumed more than 38 hours of pure cpu time.

Is it normal for a byte-recompiled-directory to take so much time to process a directory? May the abnormality be caused by my specific version of the software? Someone has to package emacs before distribution, does he spend as much time for compilation or hold some tricks up his sleeve?

---

Update I.

I does not perform separate compilation for compiler files. Just run single command

---

Update II.

I've tried batch-byte-recompile-directory, it works as fast as I've expected from modern compiler. Less than a minute was required for the compiler. And without batch the compiling process longed more than 10 minutes. Considering work time for small and larger directories I made a suggestion that 'byte-recompile-directory' have square or more time complexity depending on sources size. And most of the time is wasted due to some weird logic employed by the builder. May be some files are visited multiple times in an iterative process.

---

Update III

As @phils suggested the issue was in the emacs initialization file. Firstly I've thought that the case was in trying to compile lisp files that the emacs was using for run. So I created simple start.el file, that reset the `load-path` variable to fresh copy of lisp directory. But that was not the case. Even using target files for running emacs has done its work pretty well.

So that was some of the plugins that messed with compiler work.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I search for emacs problems in google and if often send me this site, so I was sure that the emacs tag is what I need. May the topic be transferred to the emacs.stackexchange.com? If not, is it proper to create two topics?

Comment: Did you compile and reload the compiler before compiling everything else?  That might make a significant difference.

Comment: @ayvango, the Emacs SE site is new (and beta). Some Emacs questions still fit here (ones that relate with programming) but yours is more of a systems administration question.

Comment: FYI, if I forcibly byte-compile a copy of the calc directory, it takes less than 10 seconds. Is this shell command any faster than what you were doing? `touch *.el && emacs -Q -batch -eval '(batch-byte-recompile-directory 0)'`

Comment: Potentially you should try compiling Emacs from source. If that works out, then (assuming it's your own system) you could remove the Gentoo package entirely.

Comment: Glad to hear it works fast with the batch command. I think the *most* likely reason for that is the `-Q` in the command I gave you, rather than anything to do with it being a batch command. You should now try just running `emacs -Q` and trying to byte-compile the way you were doing it originally. If that's also fast, then the real problem lies somewhere in your site-lisp or custom config files. (n.b. You can use `emacs -q` to omit *only* your own user config.)

Comment: You are right. I've totally forget to test issue with disabled local config. It was hard to imagine that someone would like to mess with compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte-compilation is pretty fast. If it's taking more than a matter of seconds to recompile a directory, something is amiss. (e.g. If I forcibly byte-compile a copy of the calc directory, it takes less than 10 seconds.)

If you want to eliminate as many influences from your running Emacs instance as possible, a bare-bones approach to bulk elisp byte-compilation is to do it from the shell, running Emacs with the `-Q` argument in batch mode, and calling the `batch-byte-recompile-directory` function.

e.g. Either of the following shell commands will recompile files in the current working directory (the second version passes the optional ARG through to `byte-recompile-directory`).

```
emacs -Q -batch -f batch-byte-recompile-directory

emacs -Q -batch -eval '(batch-byte-recompile-directory 0)'
```

You can also append a list of directory arguments to the shell command, to recompile those directories instead:

```
emacs -Q -batch -f batch-byte-recompile-directory ~/.emacs.d/lisp ~/.emacs.d/elpa/haskell-mode-13.7
```

Similarly for `batch-byte-compile` which compiles a list of individual files:

```
emacs -Q -batch -f batch-byte-compile *.el
```

You can use `-L` to add directories to the load-path, if necessary:

```
emacs -Q -L ~/.emacs.d/elpa/haskell-mode-13.7 -batch -f batch-byte-recompile-directory ~/.emacs.d/elpa/haskell-mode-13.7

emacs -Q -L . -batch -f batch-byte-recompile-directory

emacs -Q -L . -batch -f batch-byte-compile *.el
```

Or maybe you want to initialize the package system first:

```
emacs -Q -batch -f package-initialize -f batch-byte-recompile-directory ~/.emacs.d/elpa/haskell-mode-13.7
```

You get the idea.

Note that if this improves the performance, it's most likely because of the `-Q` argument (rather than being anything to do with running Emacs in batch mode), in which case you should investigate your site-lisp and/or personal config for the cause of the problem.